# Nuxt Generate fails on Cloudflare Pages to build

Tags: nuxt.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-pages

```
19:57:39.125     Executing user command: nuxt generate
19:57:40.032    
19:57:40.032     ERROR  (node:1364) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
19:57:40.032    
19:57:40.034    
19:57:40.035     FATAL  Unexpected token '.'
19:57:40.035    
19:57:40.035      at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:81:18)
19:57:40.035      at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:37:21)
19:57:40.035    
19:57:40.039    
19:57:40.039       ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
19:57:40.039       │                                       │
19:57:40.039       │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                  │
19:57:40.039       │                                       │
19:57:40.039       │   SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'   │
19:57:40.039       │                                       │
19:57:40.040       ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯
19:57:40.040    
19:57:40.050    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
19:57:41.186    Failed: an internal error occurred
```

I am deploying a Static NuxtJS to Cloudflare Pages, but I keep receiving this error above, the NuxtJS app builds and generates fine on my local machine but not Cloudflare pages, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Not sure but maybe some of your packages are not not compatible with Cloudflare Pages (or is it regular Node env there rather than serverless functions)?

Comment: @kissu - Hey, It's a vanilla NuxtJS installation with Tailwind. They supposedly support NuxtJS and Tailwind, I've opened a ticket.